# Automatically create a column for a non-existing week

Tags: excel, vba

I want to import a table from a client that a schedule is for 13 weeks
after importing this file, check if there is 13 weeks if not add another column for the missing week with a 0
any idea?

Comment: More details, a screenshot, and some code would be helpful. You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71372637/edit) at any time.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.